# How to get water flowing back into refrigerator after installing a water filter?

Tags: plumbing, water, valve

I shut the valve off on the Hammer Arrestor, then added an inline water filter, but when the valve is on no water is coming out.  Do I need to turn the water supply off to the house and then turn it on again to get the water flowing into the refrigerator?

Comment: Did you remove any seals the new filter had?  No you don’t need to turn off the house main, you have another problem.

Comment: Agree with Tyson , also have you Tryed to flow the water for several minutes you need to purge the air out of the filter and water lines that may have drained out.